# Geocoder returns USA results when GB is being specified

Tags: laravel, google-maps, geocoding, laravel-5.4, google-geocoder

I am using a [Laravel plugin](https://github.com/alexpechkarev/google-geocoder) to geocode a city into latitude and longitude.

This is what is sent:

`$param = [
    'address' => $place,
    'country:GB',
    'types' => ["cities"]
 ];`

Unfortunately, Google keeps returning all of the results from USA, not GB!

I have added the country and types into a `components` array, and it still returns USA results.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're sending the country wrong. in the docs:

To restrict your results to a specific area use component filter Component Filtering by adding it's filters to parameter array.

```
$param = array(
            "address"=>"76 Buckingham Palace Road London SW1W 9TQ",
            "components"=>"country:GB"
        );
```